# How can I use the AEST timezone with Moment.js?

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs

I'm using moment.js to convert from a given time in a timezone to the same time in the current timezone.

My data is specified in the following format:

```
{ 
    "start": "2013-12-10T09:00:00Z",
    "end": "2013-12-10T11:00:00Z",
    "timezone": "AEST"
}
```

I can successfully convert the moment in the specified format to my current timezone, for example:

```
var time = moment('2013-12-24T09:00:00Z').tz('Europe/London');
console.log(time.format('DD-MMM-YYYY'));
console.log(time.format('h:mm:ss a'));
```

But 'AEST' is not in the timezone data I retrieved from the [Moment.js timezone data builder](http://momentjs.com/timezone/data/) - it has instead "Aus EST". AEST seems to be a common abbreviation (according to [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations), at least).

Is Moment.js following a particular standard? Has anyone else run into issues with missing (or differently named) timezones?

Comment: AFAIK "AEST" is commonly used within Australia to refer to Australian Eastern Standard Time -- I've seen it on media shows, newspapers and online promotional offers during my time there. Not sure about the motive behind Moment.js choosing "Aus EST" for the name though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The data coming from the moment-timezone data builder is *not* using "Aus EST" as a time zone abbreviation.  I believe you are confused because you are seeing something like this:

```
moment.tz.add({
    "zones": {
        "Australia/Brisbane": [
            "10:12:8 - LMT 1895 10:12:8",
            "10 Aus EST 1971 10",
            "10 AQ EST"
        ]
    },
    "rules": {
        "Aus": [
            "1917 1917 0 1 7 0:1 0 1",
            "1917 1917 2 25 7 2 0 0",
            "1942 1942 0 1 7 2 0 1",
            "1942 1942 2 29 7 2 0 0",
            "1942 1942 8 27 7 2 0 1",
            "1943 1944 2 0 8 2 0 0",
            "1943 1943 9 3 7 2 0 1"
        ],
        "AQ": [
            "1971 1971 9 0 8 2 2 1",
            "1972 1972 1 0 8 2 2 0",
            "1989 1991 9 0 8 2 2 1",
            "1990 1992 2 1 0 2 2 0"
        ]
    },
    "links": {}
});
```

The `"Aus"` here is referring to the internal *rule* labeled "Aus", and the abbreviation used is simply EST.  You can also see that there is a second rule for this zone, labeled `"AQ"`.  These rule names are just labels so that the zone data can refer to them.  You shouldn't pay any attention to rule names, just the zone names themselves, such as `"Australia/Brisbane"` shown here.

This data comes directly from the [IANA/Olson time zone database](http://iana.org/time-zones).  Moment.js is simply compiling it down to a more compact JSON format.  You can find the original rules for Australia [here](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/master/australasia).

If you want, you can read the commentary in that same file which has a lenghthy discussion regarding whether to use AEST or EST as the abbreviation.  But the points can be boiled down to this:

- In Australia, many just say just "Eastern Time" instead of "Australian Eastern Time"
- Here in America, we don't go around saying "American Eastern Time", so why should they?
- Even if we did, then *both* would be AEST, so that would not help.

This is actually just one example of how *there is no standard for time zone abbreviations*.  There are *many* other conflicts, such as "CST" which has at least 5 different meanings, "IST" which has at least 3, and many many others.  There are even conflicts in a single area, such as Hawaii which is quite often labeled "HST", but is legally "HAST" (Hawaii-Aleutian Standard Time).  You can go through [this list of abbreviations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations) if you want more examples.

So in general, you cannot rely on a time zone abbreviation for anything other than for display.  You should not be passing `"AEST"` in the JSON data.  Instead, pass `"Australia/Brisbane"`, or whatever the actual IANA/Olson time zone identifier is.  You can find a complete list of valid zone identifiers [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).  You can also review the specifics for just Australia [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_australia#IANA_time_zone_database).

If your data is coming from a third party, you should request they change their API accordingly, so it is actually usable.

Another reason why "AEST" isn't a good identifier is that zones like `Australia/Brisbane` use it year round, while zones like `Australia/Sydney` use AEST in the winter months, and AEDT during the summer months.  So just having AEST isn't enough to uniquely identify the time zone.

Comment: Brilliant answer, thanks for taking the time to explain!